Can I use NVIDIA GPUs on Linux in 2024?
My question is: If I'm building a PC and I want to use Linux on it, can I choose an NVIDIA card for it or is an AMD Radeon a better option?
I asked this question in some PC Building forums, and what they could tell me is that AMD has better open-source drivers and they had / heard of some "headaches" with NVIDIA gpus. However I read a lot of articles about NVIDIA also releasing open-source drivers, how to make it work on Wayland etc. So, as most of the people in those PC hardware forums are windows users anyway, I wanted an opinion from the software side: Is it in 2024 still a bad idea to use NVIDIA Geforce GPUs on Linux? And what "headaches" could bring it?
When saying "Linux" I mean Mint / Ubuntu at first, I read that it'd be easy to install NVIDIA drivers with the ubuntu-drivers command, but maybe I'd also like to try some Arch or other distros, I think I'd have to manually install them there, but it also seem to be not too complicated.
I have no problem with using proprietary drivers, and would prefer the real NVIDIA drivers over Nouveau.

Yes, one can use Nvidia GPUs on a Linux distro in 2024 as has been the case for a while. Whether you use Nvidia or AMD Radeon depends on your use case and any answers will largely be opinion-based.

@NasirRiley nice thank you

Close voters: How is this opinion based? The question is whether or not NVDIA cards can work with Linux systems, and the answer is a simple yes. The question isn't asking if they're better, only if they work and that isn't a question of opinion.

@terdon exactly. You got it

@terdon NVIDIA is still a headache to get working fine with Wayland and multiple monitors, so no, this depends very much on the actual configuration being used and what level of usability someone is comfortable with (which is very much opinon-based).

(I run GDM on multiple displays with Wayland on NVIDIA for my login screen, but my actual session still uses X due to various applications taking objection to this setup.)

OK, but that sounds more like an answer, really, @muru. I mean sure, it may depend on the specifics, but that again isn't a question of opinion, it just means my answer is lacking a lot of detail. The can question is still definitively answered with "yes", it just comes with some warnings for Wayland users.

@terdon that is ignoring the rest of the post: "is an AMD Radeon a better option?", "Is it in 2024 still a bad idea to use NVIDIA Geforce GPUs on Linux?" both of which are 100% questions of opinions, not to mention the unfocused, open-ended 'And what "headaches" could bring it?'

@muru sorry for my unclear question, I think it's not that opinion-based but it depends a lot on the use case: for me, I don't need to use multiple monitors and I'm also fine using X, but I also saw an article that explains setting up Wayland on Arch with NVIDIA cards. I just want to know how "usable" (meaning how easy to setup & what kind of bugs or limitations
could occur) that would be compared to the same situation with an AMD card. Should've said that.

Yes, of course you can. Both AMD and NVIDIA cards work with Linux systems. You might have some issues with specific cards, perhaps, if they require something very special (I don't know of any that do), but the vast majority of graphics cards will indeed work just fine on Linux.
For NVIDIA specifically, you can either use the proprietary drivers maintained by NVIDIA themselves, or use the open source nouveau drivers. The choice of which one is yours, depending on your hardware, usecase and choice. There was a brief window several years ago where ATI (AMD, today) cards were better supported on Linux systems, but then there came a time that NVIDIA cards were better supported, and these days I think we are in a time when there isn't much difference in support between the two.
